# How to open a new tab when I select a option in Select Tag?

Tags: javascript, html

#### I want to open a new tab when I select any of the options in the select box how to implement it ?

Html code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Select the country you want to know about</h1>
    <br>
    <form>
        <select name="Countries and its Name" onchange="location = this.value;">
            <option selected>---Select---</option>
            <option value="india.html">India</option>
            <option value="usa.html">United States of America</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

I am only able to open it in the same tab, but how to open in a new tab?

Comment: This is an odd UI choice, be aware some users may try to navigate through the select using arrow keys and open a new tab with each keypress.

Comment: @DBS ohh, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a new tab programmatically using[`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method by passing `_blank` as window name.

```html
<h1>Select the country you want to know about</h1>
<br>
<form>
  <select name="Countries and its Name" onchange="window.open(this.value, '_blank')">
    <option selected>---Select---</option>
    <option value="india.html">India</option>
    <option value="usa.html">United States of America</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh this did work for me, but is there a way without using js ?

Comment: @MochironDesu not with a `<select>` element. You can use an `<a href="" target="_blank">